# post data to a webservice soap based

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services

Guys I know how to post data to a webservice but I dont know how to post xml data to a soap based webservice in vb.net.Also if you could show me how to accept xml based response from the web service that would be strongly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to perform serialization and deserialization yourself ? .Net framework Itself takes care of these operations .

Comment: could show me any piece of code for me or example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use XMLHttpRequest - like below sample

```
Dim strEnvelope As String
    Dim request As New MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest
    Dim strReturn As String
    Dim objReturn As New MSXML.DOMDocument
    Dim strQuery As String



    Private Sub btnAcct_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnResidentAcct.Click

        strEnvelope = "POST /Account/Account.asmx HTTP/1.1 " & _
        "Host: 1.1.1.1" & _
        "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" & _
        "Content(655) : length()" & _
        "SOAPAction: ""http://www.account.net/Account/Account""" & _
              "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" & _
          " <soap:Body>" & _
            "<Account xmlns=""http:// www.account.net/Account "">" & _

              "</Account>" & _
           "</soap:Body>" & _
         "</soap:Envelope>"


        'Set up to post to our localhost server
        request.open("post", "http:// www.account.net/Account ")
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
        request.setRequestHeader("Account", "http://www.account.net/Account/Account")
        request.send(strEnvelope)
strReturn = request.responsetext
  objReturn.loadXML(strReturn)

        strQuery = "SOAP:Envelope/SOAP:Body/m:AccountResponse/Account"
```